# Lines through the origin every pair of which meet at the same angle

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, projective-geometry, euclidean-geometry

[This item](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3918780/lines-through-the-origin-every-pair-of-which-meet-at-the-same-angle) isn't getting attention, so I'll try it here:

**begin quote**

The three lines through antipodal pairs of centers of faces of a cube meet each other pairwise at $90^\circ$ angles.

The three lines through antipodal pairs of centers of faces of an octohedron meet each other pairwise at angles of $\arccos\tfrac 1 3.$

The three lines through antipodal pairs of faces of a dodecahedron meet each other pairwise at equal angles. (If faces $A$ and $B$ do not share an edge and are not antipodal to each other, then $A$ and the face antipodal to $B$ share an edge.)

If you do the same with an icosahedron, not all pairs meet at the same angle, but rather there are two (but only two, I was mildly surprised to realize) different angles that occur.

(And with a tetrahedron, there are no antipodal faces.)

So a question is: For which angles is there a maximal set of lines through the origin such that every pair of them meet at the same angle?

In dimension $2,$ only $90^\circ$ and $60^\circ$ work.

**end quote**

Another way to look at it: How big can a finite set of point in a real projective space get while all pairs of distinct points in the set are at the same distance from each other and no additional point is at that same distance from all of them? In one dimension, you can have two or three but no more. In two dimensions, you can have three, four, or six, and I don't know whether others are possible.

Comment: it is called equiangular set and was studied a lot

Comment: @FedorPetrov : So "a lot" isn't enough for it to get an answer where I first posted it. (But at first I expected the answer to be at least moderately widely known.) I wonder if you can be more specific.

Comment: Well, the answer of Fedor gives you the correct terminology. Perhaps you can expand your question with saying whether you looked at the references in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equiangular_lines , for example, and what you want to know beyond what is explained in those references.

Comment: If by "maximal" you mean "no further line can be added", then such a set of of lines exists for *any angle $\alpha\le90^\circ$*. Consider the set of lines spanned by vectors $e_i + (s,...,s)$, where the $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors, and $s$ is an appropriately chosen number. For $s=0$ you have $\alpha=90^\circ$, and for $s\to\infty$ you find $\alpha \to 0^\circ$.

Comment: @M.Winter : ok, You have identified a flaw in the way I phrased the question. Note that your example only allows as many lines as the dimension of the space, whereas my examples are not so limited.